# Intellij: Run crossProject test (Scala / Scala.js) does not work

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, scala.js

I have a Scala / Scala.js Crossproject. ([scala-adapters-wizard](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters-wizard))

I cannot run my 'shared' Scala Tests in Intellij.

If I open the Configuration, I can select the Module (sharedJVM).

But this gives the following exception:
[image]

The test classes are in `/shared/.jvm/target/scala-2.12/test-classes`.

Comment: It seems to be [a bug in IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13423).